Problem with SQL entity connection string
I have an app that is called on a remote web hosting server. It calls up customer details and amends records in response to notification of a sale. It used to work fine but recently it does not.
The exception is:

System.ArgumentException: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
at GSnet.Models.GreenhillSoftwareEntities..ctor() in C:\Users\Mike\source\repos\GSnetA\Models\GsEntityModel1.Designer.cs:line 50
at GSnet.GSData.ProcessPurchase(Transaction payPalTransaction) in C:\Users\Mike\source\repos\GSnetA\GSData.cs:line 58

I have double checked the connection string and cannot see anything wrong with it. Here it is below with XXXs replacing sensitive data.
<add name="xxxxSoftwareEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.GsEntityModel.csdl|res://*/Models.GsEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.GsEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxxx.net;initial catalog=xxxxx_db;user id=greenhi1;password=xxxxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

If I run it on my dev machine to debug it calls the remote database quite happily but when the same code and the same connection string are on the remote hosting server then it falls over the first time it calls for any data.
I have racked my brain to remember any significant changes, consulting my GIT history etc. but I am stumped.
Can anyone give me any pointers?
I have tried recopying both the code and the connections string/web.config to the server and added some logging so I know which version of the code is running. It still failed.

Did you have one project with the entityFramework and another one with the webApp in your solution?

You're still using System.Data.SqlClient instead of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient? What versions of System.Data.SqlClient do you have installed locally and remotely?

Any useful clues in this previous question, The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid?

You can try to build the connectionstring with some help from microsoft. Create a  text file anywhere and rename it so it has extension .udl Now doubleclick on that file from windows explorer, now you have a tool that can assist a little in building a working connection string. When you get it working in this tool, then open the udl text file with notepath and you will get the connectionstring as text again

Thanks for the feeback. In answer to questions
It is all one solution on my dev machine. I copied the .dll, .pdb, EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll & EntityFramework.dll to the bin folder of the hosting server.
The EntityFramework is 6.400.420.21404 on both local and remote.
I am not using System.Data.SqlClient but System.Data.EntityClient

On the web site there is another web.config in a subdirectory. It has connection strings for two other web services
